# Postman: Retrieve JSON value from attribute name having dots

Tags: json, google-chrome, postman

Below is the response format from one of the REST API, I need to retrieve only `abc` not `TOKEN_abc`. I am using Postman:

```
{
  "app.access.token": "TOKEN_abc"
}
```

I tried using the below code and it is not working:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.app.access.token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 'dots' in the key you would need to reference it in brackets, the way you have it is telling it to find the 'app' key then the 'access' key and finally get the value of the 'token' key - Adding something like this to your environment set function should work:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json()
pm.environment.set("token", jsonData['app.access.token']);
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with the dotted property name. It's probably the way you map it. Try this:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.app.access.token);
```